# Multiline grok of consecutive events of the same type with joining

Tags: logstash

Consider this log file structure:

```
patA1 .*? patA2 .*? patA3
... (many lines here)
patB1 .*? patB2 .*? patB3
patB1 .*? patB2 .*? patB3
```

In the above, consider `patXY` to be different regex patterns, i.e. the first line above could be `grok`ked via something like this:

```
grok {
  match => { 
    "message" => "%{patA1:keyA1} (?<afterA1:.*?) %{patA2:keyA2} (?<afterA2:.*?) %{patA3:keyA3}"}
  }
}
```

I'd like to `multiline` the above and then generate events from multiple lines as such:

```
event1: keyA3, keyB1, keyB3
event2: keyA3, keyB2, keyB3
```

That is, pick some part(s) from line A and add that to each of the B lines, ending up with as many events as there are Bs.

In other words, I'd like to process the above as if doing single-line processing of log lines such as:

```
patA1 .*? patA2 .*? patA3 .*? patB1 .*? patB2 .*? patB3
patA1 .*? patA2 .*? patA3 .*? patB1 .*? patB2 .*? patB3
```

from which I can pick items with grok alone.

Note that the lines are of the same structure, so when using `multiline`, the message for the above looks like:

```
"message" => "patA1 .*? patA2 .*? patA3\npatB1 .*? patB2 .*? patB3\npatB1 .*? patB2 .*? patB3"
```

i.e. it has A and all Bs in the same "block", since Bs are consecutive and all are of the same shape.

What's the best way to do this in logstash?

Answer (score 0):

First grok like this:

```
grok {
  match => {
    "message" => ".*?(?<keyA3>patA3}"
  }
}
```

This will add `keyA3` to the event. Then split:

```
split {}
```

This will split by `message` by default, giving you cloned events for each of the lines, thus keeping `keyA3` from this event. Then filter B lines only:

```
if ([message] !~ /patB1/) {
  drop {}
}
```

Then grok again for the rest of the needed info:

```
grok {
  match => {
    "message" => "(?<keyB1>patB1) .*? (?<keyB2>patB2) .*? (?<keyB3>patB3)"
  }
}
```

At this point all events will have `keyA3`, `keyB1`, `keyB2` and `keyB3` that you can use as needed.